# jQuery autocomplete search and select programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a data from my controller and when the page loads I want the autocomplete input to search for that data and select it.

I am able to search the data using:

`$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete( "search", '<?=$ID?>' );`

above code works and showing the correct value of autocomplete. Now I cant select the value so that the autocomplete input triggers change. I wanted the input to trigger change because I will auto populate some input.

The way I select the value pro grammatically is :

`select: function( event, ui ) {}`

Now i found this:

`search: function( event, ui ) {},`

Is is possible to combine the two?

How to select searched data from auto complete programmatically ?

Update:

This is how my autcomplete works:

```
$( ".updatedautocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source:function(request,response){
         var $this = $(this);
         $.post("url",{
            term:request.term
         }).done(function(data, status){
            response($.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    data
                }
                return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
            }));

        });
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
         $( this ).attr( 'data-value' , ui.item.id );
         $( this ).attr( 'data-asd' , ui.item.sad );
         $( this ).val( ui.item.label );
         $( "#modal" ).val( ui.item.qwe.trim() );
         $( "#modal" ).val( ui.item.asd.trim() );
         $( "#modal" ).val( ui.item.zxc.trim() );
         $( "#modal" ).val( ui.item.ert.trim() );
         $( "#modal" ).val( ui.item.dfg.trim() );
        return false;
      }
    });
```

The reason why I wanted select event is to populate some input as shown in the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the input element, like so.

#### Edit

Since you seem to want to trigger the selection after an asynchronous data retrieval, you probably want the [`response`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event and perform the selection there.

**response (event, ui)**

> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are no results or the Autocomplete is disabled

```js
$(".updatedautocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var $this = $(this);

    //$.post("url", {
    //  term: request.term
    //})
    //.done(function (data, status) {
    //  response($.map(data, function (item) {
    //      return {
    //        data
    //      }
    //      return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
    //    }));
    //
    //});

    // Simulates some data returned from server
    response([
      { label: "Javascript", value: "js" },
      { label: "CSharp", value: "cs" },
      { label: "PHP", value: "php" }
    ]);
  },
  response: function(event, ui) {
    // Make your preferred selection here
    var item = ui.content[0].label;

    $(this).val(item).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="updatedautocomplete" />
```

[`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search) and [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) are the events which get triggered when the search is taking place. You don't execute them.

Additionally, I believe the method [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) (not the event one) is meant rather for "suggesting" users that a value/tag exists in the list and that they need to select it themselves. So, yes, if you need a value programmatically selected (without user interaction) you might need to do it by [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and optionally [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: this will not initialize the auto complete i need to initialize the autocomplete first

Comment: @guradio It actually will if you provide the `source` of tags correctly. After all, I thought your question is about how to programmatically select a value and that you have the initialization logic in place?

Comment: i tried it but not selection was shown and selected

Comment: Can you please post how you are populating the tags and where you are triggering the select?

Comment: So you need to fetch the tags asynchronously. I don't have a sample data to simulate the Ajax calls for testing. But is the returned data in the following format? `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Comment: OK, gimme a sec to figure this out. I think I've done something like that before.

Comment: So just to be sure, when the data is fetched from server and you get the selected tags, let's say there are 3 possible choices, so which value do you want selected?

Comment: Answer updated, let me know if that's what you need?

Comment: one more question for example the user completed typing instead of selecting from the autocomplete suggestion what event should i fire to get the equivalent suggestions?

Comment: If they completed typing any **existing** value contained in the list, there should be no more work to do, I don't see why we need to trigger any more event at this point. What would you need to do by then though?

Comment: is there an event to close the opened suggestion on autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, try [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-close). Like `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "close" );`.